# How to find if a word is in a text file and add the name of the file to a dictionary?

Tags: python

I've been stuck on this problem:

I am given a list of text files (e.g. 'ZchEuxJ9VJ.txt', 'QAih70niIq.txt') which each contain a randomly generated paragraph. I am to write a parser that will extract the individual words from each of the files listed in the folder. My end goal is to create a dictionary with keys that represent the individual words found in my files. The values are supposed to be a list of files that contain that word. For example, if I print `('happy:', search['happy'])`, the files that contain the word `happy` should be added as values to my dictionary. If the word is a "new" word I would have to set it up for the first time. If the word is not a "new" word I would have to update the list associated with that word. I also have to make sure that I don't add the same filename to the same word twice.

I've already created a new dictionary called `search`, visited each of the files and opened them for reading, then isolated each word using the `split()` method. The thing I am struggling with is how to "find" a word in a particular file and mark down which file a word can be found in. I've tried "searching" for a word in a file then adding the file to the dictionary, but that gets me an error message.

Comment: Hi, please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for words in files, you should be going about it the other way around. You know you need to index every word in every file eventually, so why not just go through every word in every file, in order? In pseudocode it might look something like this.

```
for each file:
    for each word in file:
        if not word in search:
            search[word] = []
        search[word].append(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is homework, so I'm going to help you with the algorithm, not the code. You seem to have figured out most of the problem. The only thing you need help with is how to actually populate the dictionary.

1. Open the file (say `fname`), read its contents
2. Split the contents to separate each word
3. Iterate over each word. Say we call it `fword`.

   1. Is `fword` in the dictionary?

      1. No? Create the key with an empty list as the value
      2. Yes? Do nothing and move on
   2. Now you know that `fword` is a key in the `search` dictionary, and its value is a list. (Say we call this list `fwlist`)
   3. You also know that `fword` was found in the file `fname`
   4. Check if `fname` is already in `fwlist`

      1. No? Add `fname` to `fwlist`.
      2. Yes? Don't add it again. Do nothing.

Now, there are optimizations you can make, such as using a `set` instead of a `list`. This way you don't need to check if `fname` already exists in `fwlist`, because sets automatically discard duplicates, but this should be enough for what you need.

Remember: before you start writing the program, it's helpful to sit down, think about the problem you're trying to solve, and plan out how you're going to attack the problem. Drawing a flowchart helps immensely when you're a novice programmer because it helps you organize your thoughts and figure out how your program is supposed to flow.

Debugging is also a crucial skill -- your code is useless if you can't fix errors. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)